# systemctl status gunicorn error when deploying django project on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04

I want to deploy a django project on ubuntu 20.4 on digital ocean. I'm using gunicorn and nginx. The project structure:

```
./
    e-marketplace/
        account/
        bin/
        env
        home/
        logistics/
            stettings.py
            wsgi.py
        manage.py
        requirements.txt
        staticfiles/
        ...
```

The process was going well until I got to the point where I'm to connect my project to gunicorn. I set up the `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket` and `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` files as shown below:
[image]
[image]
However I keep getting the follow error when I run the command `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.socket`  as well as  `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` command:
[image]
I have spent about 3 day trying to solve the problem without any positive outcome

I went through digital ocean documentation
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04
but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I checked the answer to  similar question on the internet, including other stack overflow reviews but I still could not find the solution that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`:
`[Servic]` instead of `[Service]`.